# Can iTunes be loaded onto my iphone7?

Tags: itunes, music, library, iphone

Sorry for my ignorance. I want to play my iTunes library of songs on my iPhone when in the car like I do when on my PC at home. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Open iTunes and the help in the app describes the steps to sync content to iOS.

Or start here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201253

Comment: Tks bmike but if I did sync would it sync all my own songs from the library or just the ones that I have purchased thru iTunes? Is there any danger that it could wipe my own private library of songs?

Comment: You can sync anything that's on iTunes on the computer, purchased from the store or your own ripped CDs. It will overwrite anything on the phone that isn't on the computer, though. [Apple Music works differently, but that's how a basic iTunes>iPhone sync works]

Comment: @Buster - thats answered in other questions. Also, nothing deletes without you seeing a prompt in iTunes. Depends on what exactly is on your device.